# json_encode(): Sending both a Table and Variables from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

From my PHP script I have to send to JavaScript two pieces of data in one AJAX return call:

- relatively large array with app. 200 rows and 10 columns
- set of variables providing additional information about that array

Both pieces of information should be returned from PHP to JavaScript in **one JavaScript return call**.

A standard way of sending arrays from PHP is by using `json_encode()`. This function however accepts only one parameter, either a string or an array.

How to, please, send both the table and variables from PHP to JavaScript then? If `json_encode()` wont handle this task, is there any other reliable way?

I have tried combining the variable set and the table into one array, and passing that array to JavaScript. This worked, however, when I wanted to get lenght of such array, where table and variables were combined, it simply did not work. Which is the reason, why I came to consult this problem here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Put both the table array and the variable set, into one single array and json encode it.

Comment: @kums: Hi and thanks for the idea. Yes, I have done that. However, I came to another problem. In JavaScript, I have to get `json_array.length` and this did not work for this irregular two dimensional array. I came to idea, that I have to solve the problem in its origin and thus separating variable set and table before sending it to JavaScript.

Comment: what I meant: $package = Array($dbarray, $vars); json_encode($package);

Comment: @kums: works well. Thank you very much. If you write short answer, instead of this comment, I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package the table array and the variable set array in to one single array:

```
$package = Array($dbarray, $vars); 

$json_data = json_encode($package);
```